# Haskell: 'do [1,2,3]; ["hello"]' behavior clarification

Tags: haskell, monads, do-notation

So I'm trying to understand exactly how the Haskell `do` notation works. 
I understand that it is used together with monads and that it basically expands (since it's actually syntactic sugar) into anonymous functions connected with either bind (`>>=`) or then (`>>`) as shown here https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Syntactic_sugar#Do_notation.

However **my question is** why the following command

```
Prelude> do [1, 2, 3]; "hello"
```

returns

```
"hellohellohello"
```

I know that arrays are actually monads (and that strings are arrays of chars) but I fail to see how this results in the behavior above.

Comment: Also, the right term is “lists”, as “arrays” are usually understood to be arranged consecutively in memory.

Comment: `do x <- ["baby, ", "darling, ", "ragtime gal"]; "hello my " ++ x`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
do [1, 2, 3]; "hello"
```

desugars to

```
[1, 2, 3] >> "hello"
```

which is the same as

```
[1, 2, 3] >>= (\_ -> "hello")
```

which is the same as

```
concatMap (\_ -> "hello") [1, 2, 3]
```

which is the same as

```
concat (map (\_ -> "hello") [1, 2, 3])
```

which is the same as

```
concat [(\_ -> "hello") 1, (\_ -> "hello") 2, (\_ -> "hello") 3])
```

which is the same as

```
concat ["hello","hello","hello"]
```

which is the same as

```
"hellohellohello"
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks! Now that I knew what I was looking for it seems this is (more or less) how the bind `>>=` operator is defined for arrays (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#Syntactic_sugar:_do-notation )
The important part being `m >>= f  = concat (map f m)`

Comment: I think the key point here is that `list >>= f` is defined as `concatMap f list`. The intuition is that a list represents a nondeterministic computation, so `[1,2,3]` is a computation with three possible outputs. When you bind that with a function, the result is that function applied to all possible outputs.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Joachim Breitner's answer, here's a look at this from another angle:

```
do [1, 2, 3]
   "hello"
```

is

```
do a <- [1, 2, 3]
   b <- "hello"
   return b
```

is

```
do a <- [1, 2, 3]
   do b <- "hello"
      do return b
```

is

```
[b | a <- [1,2,3], b <- "hello"]
```

is the same as the pseudocode

```
for a in (a list of Nums) [1, 2, 3]:
   -- here we have `a` (a Num)
   for b in (a list of Chars) "hello":
      -- here we have that same `a` (a Num), 
      -- and `b` (which is a Char)
      emit b       -- whatever "emit" means
```

Of course, list comprehensions for *lists* (not "arrays") of *stuff* (whatever that stuff is, say Nums, Chars, etc.) desugar into the same `concatMap`‐using code; but it is sometimes easier to handle them mentally, either as is, or as a specification for some nested *loops*.

In fact it seems that `do`-notation could as easily have been a `for`-notation in the first place.